# Passing additional parameters to pracma::integral2

Tags: r, parameter-passing, integral

I am using `pracma::integral2` to integrate a function that sometimes requires additional parameters, but `integral2` seems not to recognise the parameters I supply.
Consider these two functions:

```
fun1 <- function(x, y) exp(-x^2 - y^2)
fun2 <- function(x, y, a) (1 / a) * exp(-x^2 - y^2)
```

If I then run

```
integral2(fun1,
      xmin = 0,
      xmax = 1,
      ymin = 0,
      ymax = 1)$Q
```

I get    0.5577463 as expected. But if I run:

```
   integral2(fun2,
          xmin = 0,
          xmax = 1,
          ymin = 0,
          ymax = 1,
          a = 1)$Q
```

I get:

```
Error in fun(x, y, ...) : argument "a" is missing, with no default
```

Trackback shows the following:

> 4. fun(x, y, ...)
> 5. FUN(X, Y)
> 6. .tensor(xmin, xmax, thetaL, thetaR, phiB, phiT, FUN, phiBvar, 
>      phiTvar, vectorized = vectorized, singular = singular)
> 7. integral2(fun2, xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = 0, ymax = 1, a = 1)

I don't know what  `.tensor` is, but it looks as if its product `FUN(X,Y)` has lost the `...`.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` is being matched to the `abstol` argument of `integral2`.  Just rename `a` to something else in `fun2` as in solution 1 below or else specify `abstol` explicitly so it does not get confused as in solution 2 below.

```
library(pracma)

# solution 1
fun2aa <- function(x, y, aa) (1 / aa) * exp(-x^2 - y^2)
integral2(fun2aa,
          xmin = 0,
          xmax = 1,
          ymin = 0,
          ymax = 1,
          aa = 1)$Q
## [1] 0.5577463

# solution 2
fun2 <- function(x, y, a) (1 / a) * exp(-x^2 - y^2) # same as in question
integral2(fun2,
          xmin = 0,
          xmax = 1,
          ymin = 0,
          ymax = 1,
          abstol = 0, # added
          a = 1)$Q
## [1] 0.5577463
```

Note that if integral2 had put the dot dot dot *before* `abstol` then it would not have been a problem.  Here `integral2a` is the same as `integral2` except the dot dot dot is placed after `ymax`.

```
# solution 3

fun2 <- function(x, y, a) (1 / a) * exp(-x^2 - y^2) # same as in question

integral2a <- function (fun, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, ..., 
  sector = FALSE, reltol = 1e-06, abstol = 0, maxlist = 5000, 
  singular = FALSE, vectorized = TRUE) {}
body(integral2a) <- body(integral2)
environment(integral2a) <- environment(integral2)

integral2a(fun2,
          xmin = 0,
          xmax = 1,
          ymin = 0,
          ymax = 1,
          a = 1)$Q
## [1] 0.5577463
```

Comment: Is there not a message here to anyone who writes functions in R packages? Most users do not want to check through a long list of default variables so that their own ... variables do not share an initial letter with that list. It destroys the whole idea of defaults.

Comment: Yes, the message is to put such arguments *after* the dot, dot, dot rather than before when writing the package.